# How to get the file name from a list of files

Tags: shell

So heres the scenario:

I need to write an automated script which picks the jar file from a directory. But the jar file will be replaced with a new jar file at regular intervals

eg: XXX/YYY/server-sdk-01.00.00-000080.000055.e0eb521.jar

the server-sdk part is constant all the time but the rest of the version numbering changes.

How can I read the file name and save it to a variable in this scenario.

I tried

```
fspec=XXX/YYY/server-sdk-*.jar 

filename="${fspec##*/}"  # get filename
dirname="${fspec%/*}" # get directory/path name
```

But here I only get server-sdk-*.jar as the filename where I expect it to be server-sdk-01.00.00-000080.000055.e0eb521.jar.

Comment: which shell? which OS?

Comment: What is not working and what is the error?

Comment: I need to get the filename. as server-sdk-01.00.00-000080.000055.e0eb521.jar, but I get it as server-sdk-*.jar

Comment: Note that the `server-sdk-*.jar` glob pattern may expand to *more than one file* in principle, so that `fspec` is not set to what you expect. Is that a possible scenario here? Is there only one jar file present in `XXX/YYY/` at any one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Double command substitunion` to rescue here for shell expansion. Consider this script

```
> set +f
> fspec=XXX/YYY/server-sdk-*.jar
> f=$(echo $(echo "$fspec"))
> echo "$f"
XXX/YYY/server-sdk-01.00.00-000080.000055.e0eb521.jar

> filename="${f##*/}"
> echo "$filename"
server-sdk-01.00.00-000080.000055.e0eb521.jar
> dirname="${f%/*}"
> echo "$dirname"
XXX/YYY
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to use `echo` to force filename expansion:

```
fspec=$(echo XXX/YYY/server-sdk-*.jar)
```

In the event that there is more than one server-sdk-*.jar file in this directory, you can do this to select only the newest one:

```
fspec=$(ls -t XXX/YYY/server-sdk-*.jar | head -1)
```